# What is a "mixing probability distribution"

Tags: probability-theory

> Given a distribution function $F$ such that $\int |x| dF(x)< \infty$ we introduce the *mixing probability measure*
>
> $$\nu (du,dw):=\frac{1}{\alpha}(w-u)1_{\{u \le 0<w \}}(u,w)dF(u)dF(w) $$
>
> I have two questions: 1) (loosely speaking) what is a *mixing probability measure*? and 2) how does $\nu$ evaluate a rectangle $A=[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2] \in \mathbf{R}$?

---

For 2) first I'm not sure of how to interpret the notation, but I guess it means $\nu(A) \mapsto \int 1_A(u,w)\frac{1}{\alpha}(w-u)1_{\{u \le 0<w \}}(u,w)dF(u)dF(w)$. If this is correct, can one intuitively say how $\nu$ evaluates a rectangle $[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]$ from the measure $P_X(x):=F(x)$? [Looking at it I believe the rectangle gets evaluated according to the product measure $P_X \otimes P_X$ but only the part in the second quadrant, and then we do some re-scaling??]

Most grateful for any help provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only familiar with mixing as a property of measures related to infinite paths, so some dynamics should be involved - there you would expect sometimes the measure to start behaving like a product one. In your case instead one defines a new measure $\nu$ based on one old measure with a CDF $F$ (let's denote that old measure as $\mu$). For this reason I find it hard to tell, why is this new measure called *mixing*. That's regarding your first question. Perhaps, it's just authors initiative to do so. Perhaps, it would have helped if you provided more context.

Regarding the second question: I think you've understood the notation correctly, though I do dislike it: the use of both $\nu(\mathrm du,\mathrm dw)$ and $\mathrm dF(u)$, and who would use $u$ and $w$ if you can use $u$ and $v$? Anyways. What is $\alpha$ here as well?

As an example of how to compute an integral, let's take a rectangle that makes all indicators go positive. That is, let $b_1 \leq 0 < a_2$. Then
$$
\nu([a_1, b_1]\times [a_2, b_2]) = \frac1\alpha\cdot \int\limits_{[a_1, b_1]\times [a_2, b_2]}(v-u)(\mu\otimes \mu)(\mathrm du\times \mathrm dv) = \frac1\alpha\left(\int_{a_2}^{b_2}v\mu(\mathrm dv) - \int_{a_1}^{b_1}u\mu(\mathrm du)\right).
$$
And other cases are treated similarly.

Comment: $\alpha $ is scaling a constant defined as $\frac {1 } {2 } \int |x|F(dx) $ which makes $\nu $ a probability measure.